# Laravel - CreateMany if not exists

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

I have a table that stores tags name as "tag"

**tag**

```
id->Integer(unique)
title->String;
url->string;(unique)
```

Also I have a table to store places named as place

**place**

```
id->Integer(unique)
title->string
latitude->string
longtitue->string
```

A place may have many tags, here is my place_tag table

**place_tag**

```
id->Integer(unique)
tag_id->Integer
place_id->Integer
```

when I try to update place I need to do this

1- check all tags posted.
2- add them to "tag" db if not created before
3- write relationship with tag and place

But I think Laravels ORM can handle it, I'm walking around but can't find a good solution.

Please see my update procedure what am I doing wrong.

```
public function update($id)
{
    $place=Place::findOrFail($id);
    $place->fill(Input::all());
    $place->save();

    $tags=explode(',',Input::get('tags'));

    $tags_data=array();
    foreach($tags as $tag) {
        $tags_data[]=new Tag(array('title'=>$tag,'url'=>$tag));
    }

    $place->tags()->detach();
    $place->tags()->saveMany($tags_data);

    return Redirect::to('admin/places');
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
$tagIds = [];

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $tag = trim($tag);
    if ($tag == '') {
        continue;
    }
    $fTag = Tag::firstOrCreate( [ 'title' => $tag, 'url' => $tag ] );

    $tagIds[] = $fTag->id; 
}

$place->tags()->sync($tagIds);
```

I assumed one Tag can be set to many Places (n:n relationship), so first you basically find tags and if it doesn't exist you create it and then using `sync` you synchronize relationship table (insert or remove data from pivot when necessary)